# What is the standard way of using selenium in production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, selenium, testing

I have written some tests for my website using selenium and javascript. I want to know the standard way of using this script in production. Locally I'm running chrome driver and testing my script. What I have tried is in `start` of my `package.json` I run my test `node test.js && react-scripts start`.What is the standard way of doing the same in production?

Comment: What will be the difference between the local and production runs? Your question is not clear enough

Comment: There won't be any difference. I just want to know how to tackle chrome driver in prod. Also, what is the standard way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there is no any difference between running the tests on your local machine and the product environment there is no reason to use your tests differently on the production.
However, it is common to run the tests on production with Jenkins or other CI/CD tools on Unix server in headless mode or with Selenium Grid etc.
In this case you will have to adjust your tests for running with Selenium Grid or in headless mode respectively, to adjust them running on Unix etc.
All this depends on YOUR actual configuration, how YOU will use it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple different ways of handling Selenium in production. For example, if you have an open source project, you may consider using GitHub Actions. Here's an example of a JavaScript Workflow from the Selenium Project: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/actions/workflows/javascript.yml
That's probably a good place to start, since it is open source and you can see how they run tests. Once you've learned that, you can try out some of the other popular solutions out there if you want (Eg: Jenkins, Azure Pipelines, AWS, Google Cloud, CircleCI, GitLab, TravisCI, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

**There is no way** for you to use selenium in production, considering that you need selenium in production, such as a *crawler*, what may be different are your dependencies, in development you will use the dependencies for testing, `selenium` will use the available `driver`, either in production or in development/testing.

**Perhaps** the arguments you use for the chosen browser may be different for the environments used (production, development, etc.), which doesn't make sense to me, because in the test you should reproduce the same scenario as in production.